# How do I get resource file values in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, embedded-resource

I'm new to Visual Basic, and I'm having issues accessing the resource file for my project.

```
Dim rm As Resources.ResourceManager = New Resources.ResourceManager("MyProjectName.My.Resources.Resources", [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly())
Dim myValue = rm.GetString(lookUpKey) 'boom Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I think the issue is with the string "MyProjectName.My.Resources.Resources".

Would I be better off moving the strings into their own resource file?

Comment: Nope it is "HD" a string name in my projects resource file. *Edit changed "value" to "name".

Comment: Do you have Reflector? Open your assembly there, go to resources, a list of resources appears, search for the one containg `HD`, copy the name (it's like `MyProjectName.Resources.resources`), remove the last `.resources` and try with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to access the resource file until I moved the .resx file into its own project and referenced that project from my main one. I also had to create a dummy class in that project so that it would compile into a DLL file.

The code for accessing the resource file is actually located in the generated Resource.resx.vb file.

I was able to access the resource file using the following code.

```
'Name of Class Library where I moved the resx file
Dim classLibraryName As String = "ResourceProj"
'Name of Resource File without the .resx suffix
Dim resourceFileName As String = "Mappings"
'Finding the assembly of the resx file, ResourceProjClass is a dummy class I created so that the dll would build.
Dim myAssembly As Assembly = GetType(ResourceProj.ResourceProjClass).Assembly

Dim rm As Resources.ResourceManager = Nothing
rm = New Resources.ResourceManager(classLibraryName & "." & resourceFileName, GetType(myAssembly)
Return rm.GetString(lookUpKey)
```

Answer (score 11):

I thought it was something similar to:

```
my.Resource.whateverhere
```

Is that not the kind of resources you are looking for?

Comment: My 2 cents on this, the code I had to use to get to my resource was `Me.GetLocalResourceObject("[ResourceKey]")`. Note that `GetLocalResourceObject` is used because the folder of the resource file is `Local_Resources`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 Global.<MyNamespace>.My.Resources.<ResourceStringName>
```

to access Resource Strings

Comment: Thank you for this. It got me really close to the answer. I had to use "Global.<MyNamespace>.My.Resources.RESOURCEMANAGER.GETSTRING(ResourceStringName)"

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the MSDN article *[Retrieving Resources with the ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* for naming convetions:

```
Dim myManager As New _
   System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", _
   myAssembly)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ResourceManager("MyProjectName.Resources", ...)`, otherwise if it's the application resources you can simply use `My.Resources.HD` (see here:[*My.Resources Object*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

or

Open *Reflector*, load your assembly there, go to resources, a list of resources appears, search for the one containg `'HD'`, copy the name (it's like *MyProjectName.Resources.resources*), remove the last `.resources` and try with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you load an external .resx file and want it to show up under intellisense My.Resources then you need to do 2 things.

First the file should be in the root of your project. Simply right click the project and do "Add Existing Item", and give it your .resx file. You should notice that there is no chevron to expand the resx file like your built-in resource file.

The last step is to highlight your resx file and go to the properties window. Under Custom Tool put "ResXFileCodeGenerator" and under the Custom Tool NameSpace put "My.Resources". You should now be able to programmatically access this resource under My.Resources.[name of the resx file].resource_item.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
Dim loginMessage As String = Global.Resources.NameOfYourResxFile.NameOFVariable
```

Comment: Please format your code by adding 4 leading space. Also, what does the code do? I have no knowledge in VB.

Comment: In c sharp then:string loginMessage = Global.Resources.NameOfYourResxFile.NameOFVariable;